# Using file.Close() with StreamWriter

Tags: c#, .net, streamwriter

I am having problems trying to use the file.Close with StreamWriter in this method, it doesn't seem to like it. Could someone demonstrate how this could be done. (The reason so, is that another method accesses a file being used and hence can't, because the file is still in use by the other method.)

Code so far:

```
private static void TrimColon()
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(@"process_trimmed.lst"))
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"process_trim.lst");
        string myString = "";
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {

            myString = sr.ReadLine();
            int index = myString.LastIndexOf(":");
            if (index > 0)
                myString = myString.Substring(0, index);

            sw.WriteLine(myString);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should close StreamReader as well.

Comment: Erm, where is it?  You forgot to wrap the StreamReader with the *using* statement.  The file is left opened.

Comment: @Hans Passant Could you demonstrate please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private static void TrimColon(String inputFilePath, String outputFilePath)
{
    //Error checking file paths
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inputFilePath))
        throw new ArgumentException("inputFilePath");
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(outputFilePath))
        throw new ArgumentException("outputFilePath");

    //Check to see if files exist? - Up to you, I would.

    using (var streamReader = File.OpenText(inputFilePath))
    using (var streamWriter = File.AppendText(outputFilePath))
    {
        var text = String.Empty;

        while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
        {
            text = streamReader.ReadLine();

            var index = text.LastIndexOf(":");
            if (index > 0)
                text = text.Substring(0, index);

            streamWriter.WriteLine(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @myermian So I would call TrimColon like: TrimColon("input.txt",output.txt") ??

Comment: Well, in your case, `TrimColon(@"process_trim.lst", @"process_trimmed.lst");`

Comment: @myermian For some reason, the code above does not automatically create process_trimmed.lst, it needs to exist :S

Comment: Because File.AppendText requires a file to exist already. If you're working with a filename that might not exist... I'll update the code.

Comment: @myermian Yes, the file does not exist, hence throws an exception

Comment: @Ben: I take it back, File.AppendText does not require the file to exist. Are you sure you're other file exists?

Comment: @myermian My bad, some typos in code, also you have some typos to : if (String.IsNullOrWhitespace(inputFilePath) should be if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inputFilePath)) and if (String.IsNullOrWhitespace(outputFilePath) should be: if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(outputFilePath)) Thanks for your help :D!

Comment: I also changed it to File.OpenText to make it more clear what the intention is.

Answer (score 4):

The StreamWriter is closed aswell as flushed due to the "using" statement. So no need to call close.

Comment: Im confused, Ivan Danilov claims its not closed and Hans Passant seems to think so as well

Comment: @Ben. Your StreamWriter is closed and flushed as it is within a using statement. But the StreamReader is not closed. Hence put that in a using statement as well.